# Какое окончание, для какой эпохи?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Как правильно сказать в наше время: *танцевать* или *танцовать*?
Было ли так же правильно, например, до 1914 года?

Answer (score 2):

С как минимум, по-моему, 1944 года словарями фиксируется только форма ***танцевать.***

Из «Орфографического словаря» Ушакова для семилетней школы 1944 года издания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В начале же XX века единственно, по-моему, правильной была только форма ***танцовать.***

Из  17-го издания «Русского правописания» Грота 1906 года издания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В наше время правильно: *танцевать*.

В словаре Ушакова *танцовать* приведено без пометки "устаревшее", из чего можно сделать вывод, что на момент выхода словаря (1935-1940) слово ещё было актуальным.